# Angular typeahead code not working on their own angular foundation webpage example code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-foundation

I am using angular foundation as form their website

http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/

and when i click on their plunker then when i type something in text box its not working

This is their plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/5bcGtC6MknYhNACpRqt4?p=preview

I want to see the minimum working example of that typeahead code.

can anyone please have a look what the issue

You can search for type ahead and click on Edit in Plunker on their website

http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/

Their code all seems fine . Even this minimum code is also not working

```
<h4>Static arrays</h4>
<pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see working demo below

```
angular.module('plunker').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
```

instead

```
angular.module('foundationDemoApp').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
```

angular.module('plunker').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['mm.foundation']);
angular.module('plunker').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
  // Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously
  $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
    return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val,
        sensor: false
      }
    }).then(function(res) {
      var addresses = [];
      angular.forEach(res.data.results, function(item) {
        addresses.push(item.formatted_address);
      });
      return addresses;
    });
  };

  $scope.statesWithFlags = [{
    "name": "Alabama",
    "flag": "5/5c/Flag_of_Alabama.svg/45px-Flag_of_Alabama.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Alaska",
    "flag": "e/e6/Flag_of_Alaska.svg/43px-Flag_of_Alaska.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Arizona",
    "flag": "9/9d/Flag_of_Arizona.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arizona.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Arkansas",
    "flag": "9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arkansas.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "California",
    "flag": "0/01/Flag_of_California.svg/45px-Flag_of_California.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Colorado",
    "flag": "4/46/Flag_of_Colorado.svg/45px-Flag_of_Colorado.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Connecticut",
    "flag": "9/96/Flag_of_Connecticut.svg/39px-Flag_of_Connecticut.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Delaware",
    "flag": "c/c6/Flag_of_Delaware.svg/45px-Flag_of_Delaware.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Florida",
    "flag": "f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg/45px-Flag_of_Florida.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Georgia",
    "flag": "5/54/Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg/46px-Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Hawaii",
    "flag": "e/ef/Flag_of_Hawaii.svg/46px-Flag_of_Hawaii.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Idaho",
    "flag": "a/a4/Flag_of_Idaho.svg/38px-Flag_of_Idaho.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Illinois",
    "flag": "0/01/Flag_of_Illinois.svg/46px-Flag_of_Illinois.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Indiana",
    "flag": "a/ac/Flag_of_Indiana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Indiana.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Iowa",
    "flag": "a/aa/Flag_of_Iowa.svg/44px-Flag_of_Iowa.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Kansas",
    "flag": "d/da/Flag_of_Kansas.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kansas.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Kentucky",
    "flag": "8/8d/Flag_of_Kentucky.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kentucky.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Louisiana",
    "flag": "e/e0/Flag_of_Louisiana.svg/46px-Flag_of_Louisiana.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Maine",
    "flag": "3/35/Flag_of_Maine.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maine.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Maryland",
    "flag": "a/a0/Flag_of_Maryland.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maryland.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Massachusetts",
    "flag": "f/f2/Flag_of_Massachusetts.svg/46px-Flag_of_Massachusetts.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Michigan",
    "flag": "b/b5/Flag_of_Michigan.svg/45px-Flag_of_Michigan.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Minnesota",
    "flag": "b/b9/Flag_of_Minnesota.svg/46px-Flag_of_Minnesota.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Mississippi",
    "flag": "4/42/Flag_of_Mississippi.svg/45px-Flag_of_Mississippi.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Missouri",
    "flag": "5/5a/Flag_of_Missouri.svg/46px-Flag_of_Missouri.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Montana",
    "flag": "c/cb/Flag_of_Montana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Montana.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Nebraska",
    "flag": "4/4d/Flag_of_Nebraska.svg/46px-Flag_of_Nebraska.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Nevada",
    "flag": "f/f1/Flag_of_Nevada.svg/45px-Flag_of_Nevada.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "New Hampshire",
    "flag": "2/28/Flag_of_New_Hampshire.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Hampshire.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "New Jersey",
    "flag": "9/92/Flag_of_New_Jersey.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Jersey.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "New Mexico",
    "flag": "c/c3/Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "New York",
    "flag": "1/1a/Flag_of_New_York.svg/46px-Flag_of_New_York.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "North Carolina",
    "flag": "b/bb/Flag_of_North_Carolina.svg/45px-Flag_of_North_Carolina.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "North Dakota",
    "flag": "e/ee/Flag_of_North_Dakota.svg/38px-Flag_of_North_Dakota.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Ohio",
    "flag": "4/4c/Flag_of_Ohio.svg/46px-Flag_of_Ohio.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Oklahoma",
    "flag": "6/6e/Flag_of_Oklahoma.svg/45px-Flag_of_Oklahoma.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Oregon",
    "flag": "b/b9/Flag_of_Oregon.svg/46px-Flag_of_Oregon.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Pennsylvania",
    "flag": "f/f7/Flag_of_Pennsylvania.svg/45px-Flag_of_Pennsylvania.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Rhode Island",
    "flag": "f/f3/Flag_of_Rhode_Island.svg/32px-Flag_of_Rhode_Island.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "South Carolina",
    "flag": "6/69/Flag_of_South_Carolina.svg/45px-Flag_of_South_Carolina.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "South Dakota",
    "flag": "1/1a/Flag_of_South_Dakota.svg/46px-Flag_of_South_Dakota.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Tennessee",
    "flag": "9/9e/Flag_of_Tennessee.svg/46px-Flag_of_Tennessee.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Texas",
    "flag": "f/f7/Flag_of_Texas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Texas.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Utah",
    "flag": "f/f6/Flag_of_Utah.svg/45px-Flag_of_Utah.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Vermont",
    "flag": "4/49/Flag_of_Vermont.svg/46px-Flag_of_Vermont.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Virginia",
    "flag": "4/47/Flag_of_Virginia.svg/44px-Flag_of_Virginia.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Washington",
    "flag": "5/54/Flag_of_Washington.svg/46px-Flag_of_Washington.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "West Virginia",
    "flag": "2/22/Flag_of_West_Virginia.svg/46px-Flag_of_West_Virginia.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Wisconsin",
    "flag": "2/22/Flag_of_Wisconsin.svg/45px-Flag_of_Wisconsin.svg.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Wyoming",
    "flag": "b/bc/Flag_of_Wyoming.svg/43px-Flag_of_Wyoming.svg.png"
  }];
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/mm-foundation-tpls-0.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.2.0/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12.columns">
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
        <a>
          <img ng-src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/{{match.model.flag}}" width="16">
          <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
        </a>
      </script>
      <div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

        <h4>Static arrays</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

        <h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">
        <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>

        <h4>Custom templates for results</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{customSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the plunker wasn't fine. The `foundationDemoApp` module was declared as `angular.module('foundationDemoApp')` instead of `angular.module('foundationDemoApp', [])` The html was pointing to a module called `plunker` as opposed to the `foundationDemoApp` module. After fixing those errors, the script actually loads.

http://plnkr.co/edit/8cZEo6pnyjqjmqcUMqmX?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, forgot to freeze the version